# How to load json data defined in a JavaScript file to a php variable

Tags: php, json

I've some JSON data in a javascript file

Data is build using javascript object literal notation;

```
var CMS = window.CMS = window.CMS || {};
CMS.Data = window.CMS.Data = window.CMS.Data || {};

CMS.Data['LANGUAGES']           = [
    {id:"chi", value:"Chinese"}, 
    {id:"spa", value:"Spanish"}, 
    {id:'eng', value:"English"}, 
    {id:"hin", value:"Hindi"}, 
];
CMS.Data['AGE_RANGE']           = [{id:'18', value:"18"}, {id:'25', value:"25"}, {id:'30', value:"30"}, {id:'35', value:"35"}, {id:'40', value:"40"}, {id:'50', value:"50"}, {id:'60', value:"60"}, {id:'70', value:"70"}, {id:'80', value:"80"}, {id:'90', value:"90"}, {id:'100', value:"100"}];
CMS.Data['HEIGHT_RANGE']        = [{id:'140-150', value:"140-150"}, {id:'150-160', value:"150-160"}, {id:'160-170', value:"160-170"}, {id:'180-190', value:"180-190"}];
```

Complete data is available at https://gist.github.com/mithunqb/675613fe985fe2afbbcf

I need to make it available in PHP array.

I cannot simply load the content and apply `json_decode`

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('data.json');
$json_array  = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

As the content inside the json file is not actually a valid JSON string, the above operation will result NULL;

How can I do this?

Comment: try to feed it an actually valid json string isn't an option?

Comment: yeah, I have already done that, but just need to know whether there is any way for loading data in format like this.

Comment: Unless you wish to conform to the JSON standards, you will have to write your own custom parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JSON string is not valid then there is **no way** to convert it to PHP array. Not a chance at any circumstances. It's obvious.
You must provide a valid JSON string.